# Reading a file - python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use the split string method to extract information from each line into a list.

Comment: What is the format of your file? You probably don’t want to throw away line information, which is what `.read().split()` will do (it splits on all whitespace).

Comment: .readlines() is probably better

Comment: @Ryan its just a table with the last,first name then exam 1 then exam 2 (until exam 4)

Comment: I don't think your for-loop does what you are expecting. It will not modify `file` in place. It is just creating a variable `line`, assigning a value to it, applying the `strip` function and then throwing that all away and starting over on the next iteration.

Comment: With `.split()` you split on any form of whitespace. That means you loose the difference between words and lines.

Comment: Where are the numbers `[94, 100, 89, 82, 87]` coming from? It appears to be the first number following the name but they are not in the same order as your example.

Answer (score 1):

Use splitlines, it's better :

```
file = open('scores.txt','r').read().splitlines()
exam_one = []
for line in file:
    line = line.split() # not strip
    exam_one.append(int(line[2])) # or better use float() since it's an exam
print(exam_one) # => [100, 82, 94, 89, 87]
```

Comment: Thanks but how does this answer my question

Comment: By the way, exam_one = `line[2]`, not `[2::8]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how is your file but I think it's something like:

```
Hopper, Grace 100 98 87 97
Knuth, Donald 82 87 92 81
Goldberg, Adele 94 96 90 91
Kernighan, Brian 89 74 89 77
Liskov, Barbara 87 97 81 85
```

Also I didn't understand what do yo want like output, but I think it's like this:

```
[['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97'], ['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81'], ['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91'], ['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77'], ['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']]
```

**I have developed this one-line code (for python 3.6):**

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as file:
    print([[value for value in line.strip().replace(',','').split()] for line in file])
```

**Same as:**

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as file:
    tmp = []
    for line in file:
        tmp.append(line.strip().replace(',','').split())
        # Also you can delete tmp = [] and replace the tmp.append(...) line to tmp = [var for var in line.strip().replace(',','').split()]
print(tmp)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97'], ['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81'], ['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91'], ['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77'], ['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']]
```

**The same as:**

```
[
    ['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97'],
    ['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81'],
    ['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91'],
    ['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77'],
    ['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']
]
```

I used like and output `print()` but you can define a variable is you want.


**PD:** I have found an easier solution:

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as file:
    print([line.split() for line in file.read().replace(',','').splitlines()])
```

Comment: Please don't imply that writing all that in one line is in any way a good idea.

Comment: @chepner I know, therefore I also write multiples line code. Preference for the programmer.

Comment: @dawg ok, I'll try do my best, but I don't know much codding.

Comment: Not dv worthy, but there is not reason to first read in the entire file with `file.readlines()` and then iterate over that with a `for` loop. Just do `for line in file:` and let Python split the lines automatically.

Comment: @dawg, Ok thanks, I didn't know about that, I will repair my code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following string that has words (separated by horizontal whitespace) and lines (separated by `\n` or vertical whitespace):

```
>>> print(data)
Hopper, Grace 100 98 87 97
Knuth, Donald 82 87 92 81
Goldberg, Adele 94 96 90 91
Kernighan, Brian 89 74 89 77
Liskov, Barbara 87 97 81 85
```

If you just use `.split()` you loose all difference between lines and words:

```
>>> data.split()
['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97', 'Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81', 'Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91', 'Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77', 'Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']
```

To maintain the difference, you need to combine `.splitlines()` with `.split()`:

```
>>> [line.split() for line in data.splitlines()]
[['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97'], ['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81'], ['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91'], ['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77'], ['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']]
```

The same concept applies to data read from files. Instead of using `.splitlines()` you can iterate over the individual lines of the file with a `for` loop:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file.txt') as f:
...    for line in f:
...       print(line.split())
... 
['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97']
['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81']
['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91']
['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77']
['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']
```

Or, if you want nested lists:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file.txt') as f:
...    print([line.split() for line in f])
... 
[['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97'], ['Knuth,', 'Donald', '82', '87', '92', '81'], ['Goldberg,', 'Adele', '94', '96', '90', '91'], ['Kernighan,', 'Brian', '89', '74', '89', '77'], ['Liskov,', 'Barbara', '87', '97', '81', '85']]
```

And if you want just one number from those lines:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file.txt') as f:
...    print([line.split()[2] for line in f])
... 
['100', '82', '94', '89', '87']
```

The form of opening a file and looping over the lines with a `for` loop or list comprehension is considered an important Python idiom. Use those rather than reading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the entire file into memory first. File objects are iterators.

```
result = []
with open('scores.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
         # E.g., fields == ['Hopper,', 'Grace', '100', '98', '87', '97']
        fields = line.strip().split()
```

It's not clear what you want as an end result; the first grade of each line, perhaps? After splitting the line, you could get that with

```
result.append(fields[2])
```

Comment: I wrote a sample result at the end of my comment.. I want to create a list containing the contents of each column

Comment: That list contains the contents of the *first* column, as I assumed in the question. It does not contain the contents of *each* (or *every*) column.

Comment: Also when I use your code it only prints the last line.

Comment: My code doesn't print *anything*, so I don't know what you are doing.